# Open activity using a expand animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I need to open a activity at the right part of the screen but still view the old activity at the left part of the screen.

It can be something like a dialog but i need to specify the position of the new activity and also remove the overlay look and feel.

how can i make this?

I have already achieve my first step. putting the activity at a specific position and see the main at the left of screen.

I have used the following style:

```
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
```

in my layout file i have setted my linear layout like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/background_login"
android:layout_gravity="top|right">
```

this way the activity goes to where i want. **now i just need to open the activity with an expand animation and close it with an collapse animation.
Can someone tell me how?**

Comment: like several app windows in normal PCs ?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're looking for [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). Multiple fragments can be shown next to each other, so one fragment can be your left part of the screen and another one be opened on the right side.

Please refer to the [Android Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) for more information.

Comment: Android introduced fragments in Android 3.0 (API level 11)... i need support version 2. does't work for me

Comment: Using the [Android support package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) you can use the Fragment and more APIs up to API level 4. This will work on Android 2.X.